# Website with samba share folders/files as "api source"?

Tags: javascript, web

**dont know how to properly word the title. try to explain it more clear:**

*imagine a samba share structured like this:*

```
-client 1
--projectx
---api
----project.json

-client 2
--projecty
---api
----project.json
```

so every client has a folder with different projects inside. inside each project is an api folder of sorts with a project.json or something that has infos about the project at hand.

is it possible to create a website that dynamically checks for these folders and project.json on a samba share and displays infos about it?

i am thinking about an approach like this because i want our producers to edit these json files in their filebrowser easily.

thx in advance.

*(its just a concept at this point and i am figuring out wether its worth looking in to or if its not even a viable option to follow - the server and structure already exists btw with hundreds of projects)*

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a web application which reads those files and then displays them to the user. The reading needs to be done on the back-end of your web application.

Comment: thx for your answer. appreciated.
so i need a backend like building a rest api that connects to these files? or am i misunderstanding?

sry, i am quite new to this and try to figure this out.

Comment: Yes. You want to create a back-end which reads these files. Then you can do something with the content of the file (e.g. render it in a user-friendly way).

Comment: ok. thank you. i will look in to that. much appreciated